# (Nextjs, Vscode) Why F12 (go to definition) goes to wrong definition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm using vs code as IDE and I have a nextjs project currently on the go on a Windows machine. When I hit **F12**(Go to definition) on a **styles.sidebar** for example, it goes to a file named (global.d.ts) which is in `/node_modules/next/types/global.d.ts`. (mainly for styles). but what I expect, it should go into a file name `Sidebar.module.css` at least, and then the CSS definition if possible.

SideBar.tsx

```
'use client'
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import styles from './Sidebar.module.css';

const SideBar = ({ isExpanded, toggleSidebar }: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const onLogoutClick = useCallback(() => {
    cookieService.deleteCookie(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    router.replace('/');
   }, [router]);

// ... rest of the code
  return (
    <aside className={`${styles.sidebar} ${isExpanded && styles.open}`}>
      <div className={styles.sidebar_inner}>
      // ...rest of the code
        <footer className="sidebar-footer">
          <MenuButtonItem icon={Lock} title={'Logout'} onClick={onLogoutClick} />
        </footer>
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@/configs/*": ["./src/configs/*"],
      "@/data/*": ["./src/data/*"],
      "@/constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
      "@/hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
      "@/hoc/*": ["./src/hoc/*"],
      "@/services/*": ["./src/services/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "*.css", "*.module.css"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Go to definition (f12) works fine with other functions. for example **onLogoutClick**. I don't know if I need to do more with tsconfig or vs code settings or even change the IDE.
PS:
Please let me know if you need any more details.
Please note, this is a nextjs project.